# Eclipse can't connect to activity manager on emulator - HelloWorld does not appear

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-activity

This appears related to:
[Android application doesn't start from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037512/android-application-doesnt-start-from-eclipse/3106897#3106897)

Even with the Android 2.2 platform is this still the accepted way to operate the emulator? i.e. 1, 2, 3 start/kill processes as described in the above post?  I am having a similar problem on WinXP with Eclipse w/ ADT plugin. Why would the activity not be able to start on the emulator? The computer has 756MB RAM if that could be the problem. The deployment is going along until Eclipse tries to deploy the activity. The emulator starts with the text "ANDROID_" and then eventually just displays the ANDROID logo, though appears to still be running just fine. Any ideas? Thanks. The code was copied from the HelloWorld tutorial. Here is the Eclipse console log including the error messages towards the end:

> [2010-06-23 15:43:26 - myHelloWorldProject] ------------------------------
>   [2010-06-23 15:43:26 - myHelloWorldProject] Android Launch!
>   [2010-06-23 15:43:26 - myHelloWorldProject] adb is running normally.
>   [2010-06-23 15:43:27 - myHelloWorldProject] Performing net.concentricllc.HelloWorld.HelloAndroid activity launch
>   [2010-06-23 15:43:27 - myHelloWorldProject] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'myHelloWorldAVD'
>   [2010-06-23 15:43:27 - myHelloWorldProject] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
>   [2010-06-23 15:43:27 - myHelloWorldProject] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2)
>   [2010-06-23 15:43:27 - myHelloWorldProject] Uploading myHelloWorldProject.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   [2010-06-23 15:43:32 - myHelloWorldProject] Installing myHelloWorldProject.apk...
>   [2010-06-23 15:48:29 - myHelloWorldProject] Success!
>   [2010-06-23 15:48:37 - myHelloWorldProject] Starting activity net.concentricllc.HelloWorld.HelloAndroid on device
>   [2010-06-23 15:51:35 - myHelloWorldProject] Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
>   [2010-06-23 15:51:36 - myHelloWorldProject] ActivityManager: android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
>   [2010-06-23 15:51:38 - myHelloWorldProject] Starting activity net.concentricllc.HelloWorld.HelloAndroid on device
>   [2010-06-23 15:53:36 - myHelloWorldProject] Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
>   [2010-06-23 15:53:36 - myHelloWorldProject] ActivityManager: android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
>   [2010-06-23 15:53:39 - myHelloWorldProject] Starting activity net.concentricllc.HelloWorld.HelloAndroid on device
>   [2010-06-23 15:55:41 - myHelloWorldProject] Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
>   [2010-06-23 15:55:41 - myHelloWorldProject] ActivityManager: android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
>   [2010-06-23 15:55:44 - myHelloWorldProject] Starting activity net.concentricllc.HelloWorld.HelloAndroid on device
>   [2010-06-23 15:57:15 - myHelloWorldProject] Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
>   [2010-06-23 15:57:15 - myHelloWorldProject] ActivityManager: android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
>   [2010-06-23 15:57:18 - myHelloWorldProject] Starting activity net.concentricllc.HelloWorld.HelloAndroid on device
>   [2010-06-23 15:58:51 - myHelloWorldProject] ActivityManager: Error type 2
>   [2010-06-23 15:58:52 - myHelloWorldProject] ActivityManager: android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?

Answer (score 9):

Go to a command prompt and run these commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Now run the emulator and then your application using:

```
adb install -r myApp.apk
```

This solved my problem

Comment: I tried running these commands in a bash shell and got this: `If 'adb' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf adb`

Comment: @user381261, you are probably not launching the command from the right directory. Try change directory to the platform-tools folder in your sdk folder, and then launching ./adb

Comment: It is likely that this is the whole path that is needed: ./sdk/platform-tools/adb

Answer (score 0):

Hi Andy what are the complete specs of your computer I have experienced the same when i tried to run any code in a slow computer.

Comment: Hi Jorgesys,
Thanks for the reply, this helped a lot.  Time for an upgrade for me!  It's probably running out of memory:  Pentium 4, 2.8GHz, 756 MB RAM.  I'll try again after the upgrade and let you know.
Best regards,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait some minutes until the emulator has loaded.
Then start application again.