# Emulator is not starting getting type 2 error

Tags: android

Can any one please help me to run my emulator. I am getting this below exceptio.

```
[2013-06-24 17:06:03 - Example] Installing Example.apk...
[2013-06-24 17:06:05 - Example] Success!
[2013-06-24 17:06:05 - Example] Starting activity com.example.stbclient.StbClientLauncher on device emulator-5556
[2013-06-24 17:06:07 - Example] Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-06-24 17:06:07 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
[2013-06-24 17:06:07 - Example] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[2013-06-24 17:06:10 - Example] Starting activity com.globems.stbclient.StbClientLauncher on device emulator-5556
[2013-06-24 17:06:12 - Example] Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-06-24 17:06:12 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:101)
[2013-06-24 17:06:12 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:82)
[2013-06-24 17:06:12 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
[2013-06-24 17:06:12 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
[2013-06-24 17:06:12 - Example] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[2013-06-24 17:06:15 - Example] Starting activity com.globems.stbclient.StbClientLauncher on device emulator-5556
[2013-06-24 17:06:18 - Example] Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-06-24 17:06:18 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
[2013-06-24 17:06:18 - Example] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[2013-06-24 17:06:21 - Example] Starting activity com.globems.stbclient.StbClientLauncher on device emulator-5556
[2013-06-24 17:06:23 - Example] Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-06-24 17:06:23 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:101)
[2013-06-24 17:06:23 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:82)
[2013-06-24 17:06:23 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
[2013-06-24 17:06:23 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
[2013-06-24 17:06:23 - Example] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[2013-06-24 17:06:26 - Example] Starting activity com.globems.stbclient.StbClientLauncher on device emulator-5556
[2013-06-24 17:06:28 - Example] ActivityManager: Error type 2
[2013-06-24 17:06:28 - Example] ActivityManager: android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
[2013-06-24 17:06:28 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:101)
[2013-06-24 17:06:28 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:82)
[2013-06-24 17:06:28 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
[2013-06-24 17:06:28 - Example] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
[2013-06-24 17:06:28 - Example] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is the emulator still connected to ADB? Check if you can see it listed in the Devices window in DDMS.

Comment: can you tried reset adb or recreate android emulator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse can't connect to activity manager on emulator - HelloWorld does not appear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106977/eclipse-cant-connect-to-activity-manager-on-emulator-helloworld-does-not-appe)

Answer (score 3):

Close eclipse and the emulator. Then run the following command

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

Running adb devices will restart the adb server.

Reload eclipse and the emulator and the problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and got fed up with this.
I tried everything kill/start server, project clean. I tried everything.

Suddenly I thought let's try to change the workspace destination. So I created a workspace folder `\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\`. 
After that again I created a new app by deleting the old one, also deleted the old AVD and created a new one using Nexus S.

It's successful.

```
[2014-03-09 06:14:29 - MyFirstApp] Uploading MyFirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554

[2014-03-09 06:14:30 - MyFirstApp] Installing MyFirstApp.apk...

[2014-03-09 06:16:24 - MyFirstApp] Success!

[2014-03-09 06:16:24 - MyFirstApp] Starting activity com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
```