# eclipse with android doesnt run application stuck at pre-launch chech stage

Tags: android, eclipse

A serious problem working with android dev with eclipse (with the plugin and sdk installed)
when trying to run an application to the emulator - the progress bar shows:

> Launching: Performing pre-launch check..

and stucks there- doesn't continue even after a couple of hours.
I tried killing the adb process, running the emulator before the app and with 'wipe user info'
but nothing helps - just stuck at this stage

I also tried the answers at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037512/android-application-doesnt-start-from-eclipse) but didn't help (mostly the same suggestion I already tried)

**edit**: sometimes(I'm not sure all the times) I'm getting this in the logs:

> [2011-11-26 11:28:14 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server
>   version from device emulator-5554 [2011-11-26 11:28:14 -
>   hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device
>   emulator-5554 [2011-11-26 11:28:16 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to debug
>   device emulator-5554

any ideas?

Comment: In Linux I have had a similar issue that the launcher gets stuck at 27% I had to kill the java process and it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this myself, seems to be a problem with updgrading the andoid sdk before the adt plugin or vice versa or what ever. anyway to solve had to:

- remove all the android plugin
- uninstall eclipse (if relevent and delete the whole folder)
- also delete the .metadata folder in the eclipse workspace and restart the computer(always a good suggestion/
- reinstall/update the android sdk
  = reinstall/unzip eclipse
- reinstall the ADT plugin
- have fun

Answer (score 0):

That's curious... I have the same problem however when I deployed my android's app that's launched in my device and for my surprise I can read the LogCat

Try seen on system device administrator if your device it's recognized by the system.