# Android app not showing in the emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I installed eclipse, android sdk, created AVD (tried with different versions), then created simple hello world program (autogenerated).

When I run it, it supposed to load up and show helloworld screen... but nothing happens. Emulator just loads up and shows android main screen. My app is nowhere to be seen.

Log:

```
[2012-05-19 19:09:34 - GameTest] Android Launch!
[2012-05-19 19:09:34 - GameTest] adb is running normally.
[2012-05-19 19:09:34 - GameTest] Performing org.test.game1.GameTestActivity activity launch
[2012-05-19 19:09:34 - GameTest] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'def_avd'
[2012-05-19 19:09:34 - GameTest] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'def_avd'
```

And that's it...

What is wrong and how can I actually load up my program?

Some clarifications: I tried to run emulator beforehand, and then running my app. I tried running emulator directly from eclipse "Run as - Android application" but still the same exact thing.

Comment: @Keyser, erm... Where? I don't know what it is, but if you mean just errors, then no, there are no errors or warnings.

Comment: @Keyser, ah, I see. I opened perspectives list, but there's nothing like that there...

Comment: Did you try opening the emulator before compiling?

Comment: **Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat**

Comment: @Keyser, ah, now I see. I opened that view, then restarted emulator, but there are no messages when I "run" my app.

Comment: @eric.itzhak I added that info to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Unfortunately nothing suggested in other replies helped, but I found a decent workaround.*

If you have an android device probably the simplest thing to do would be to connect it to usb and just hit "debug as android application" and in 3 or 4 seconds it will load up on your android device.

To use that option you need to instal USB driver package, but that is no problem.

Comment: I have followed too many advises in many sites and decided to connect my own Sony experia E phone through USB port. Nicely working without wasting time. I saw my app on my phone within some seconds.

Answer (score 8):

The thing missing is given below XML snippet in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Add this tag in your xml under activity tag, then your application will be launched on your Emulator

Answer (score 2):

clean the projects and refresh the emulator.

Other wise create new emulator and run it.

close the emulator and adb in windows task manager and

then try to create new emulator and run it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, first open the avd manager and launch the emulator, and wait until the emulator boots and android home screen shows up. Now try running the program.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but for some reason when I hit run it just opens new instance of emulator, which, again, loads just android main screen and not my app.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue when I was having one **intent-filter** for all the options, then I separated into 2 intent-filters, app started showing up

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
             android:host="java-lang-programming"
             android:scheme="android-app-google-plus-demo" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks its working my app is showing in emulator now

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I just had the same issue so here is how I fixed it in Android Studio 2.1.

In the Run configuration I had it set to start the AVD that I wanted automatically, and it would always start another AVD and none of them would have the app. So, I set the configuration to "Show Device Choose Dialog", started the AVD manually, and then when I hit Run I selected the running AVD and it popped right up. I hope it works for you too!

Also, I had set the Launch Option to start my main activity explicitly, and then I turned it back to default and it still worked after changing to default. So if it doesn't work for you the first time maybe try doing that too.

Answer (score 0):

Several things you might try :

- Make sure the emulator build version is the same as code
- Try and do :

  ```
  > adb kill-server
  > adb start-server
  ```
- Restart Eclipse?
- Check out [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506777/how-to-run-android-emulator-automatically-from-eclipse) question and follow the answer guide.
- Similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037512/android-application-doesnt-start-from-eclipse), And [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317167/helloandroid-emulator-problem) check it out

Comment: you can also reset the adb (which re-launches it) through eclipse itself .

Comment: Ok. Tried it... same thing. As I replied to other guy this is what happens: "Yes, I tried it, but for some reason when I hit run it just opens new instance of emulator, which, again, loads just android main screen and not my app."

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to click "Use Host GPU" on Virtual Device Screen and then start your device. Wait until UI of the device is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just once check build path and support android libraries and android emulator version and application support version and all

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix it myself, but nothing seemed to be working,

So I just:

1. Re-installed Visual Studio
2. Reset my phone to factory default
3. Went through the quick process of enabling USB Debugging 
   (***Settings*** > ***About phone*** > ***Software information*** > Tap ***Build number*** seven times to enable Developer options > Go to ***Developer options*** (which is just below About phone in the Settings > Search for ***USB Debugging*** and enable it)
4. Then I plugged in my phone again, and after installing ***USB driver package*** like [NewProger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/786107/newproger) suggested, I followed the usual steps to setting up my phone as an Android Emulator.

And it's working just fine now.

I can't exactly pinpoint what did it for me, but I guess there's no harm in trying all four steps, as a last resort, after backing up necessary files, and what not.

Hope this helps!