# app install on device/emulator but not starts automatically

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have installed a new setup of adb-bundle. When I run the project apk installed on device/emulator but not opens automatically. This problem is not related to coding I this it is related to eclipse setup because it happens with all projects. Please Help. Facing issue with debugging due to this problem.

Manifest.xml:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.demo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks

Comment: put your manifest file

Comment: does it start if you touch the app icon on your pone or emulator?

Comment: @rj yes it starts when i touch on app icon.

Comment: does this happen when you run it on the actual device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a problem with the adb. Open task manager and kill the adb process and restart everything and try again. If you have made some changes to the installed adb try to install it again properly.
Check the below links also,

https://lesleyharrison.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/solution-for-android-emulator-starts-but-app-doesnt-run/

[Android application doesn't start from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037512/android-application-doesnt-start-from-eclipse)